# cvtColor too Slow

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm making a project where i need to change the lightness, and contrast of an image, it's lightness not brightness.
So my code at the start was

```
for (int y = 0; y < dst.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < dst.cols; x++) {

        int b = dst.data[dst.channels() * (dst.cols * y + x) + 0];
        int g = dst.data[dst.channels() * (dst.cols * y + x) + 1];
        int r = dst.data[dst.channels() * (dst.cols * y + x) + 2];
... other processing stuff i'm doing
```

and it's good, doing it really fast, but when i try to make the hsv to hsl conversion to set the l value that i need it gets reaaaaaaally slow;

my hsl to hsl lines of code are

```
        cvtColor(dst, dst, CV_BGR2HSV);

        Vec3b pixel = dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x); // read pixel (0,0) 
         double H = pixel.val[0];
         double S = pixel.val[1];
         double V = pixel.val[2];
           h = H;
           l = (2 - S) * V;
           s = s * V;
           s /= (l <= 1) ? (l) : 2 - (l);
           l /= 2;

              /* i will further make here the calcs to set the l i want */
           H = h;
           l *= 2;
           s *= (l <= 1) ? l : 2 - l;
           V = (l + s) / 2;
           S = (2 * s) / (l + s);

           pixel.val[0] = H;
           pixel.val[1] = S;
           pixel.val[2] = V;

           cvtColor(dst, dst, CV_HSV2BGR);
```

and i ran it and was slow, so i was take of the lines to see which one was making it slow and i figure out it was `cvtColor(dst, dst, CV_BGR2HSV);`
So there's a way to make it faster than using cvtCOlor, or its time issue is something that can be handled?

Comment: Iterating over the whole image and changing the pixel values is not a good idea and would take a large amount of time, So I would suggest you to use inbuilt OpenCV methods such as `split()` to split the image into constituent channels and work on each channel individually, also there are `multiply()`, `divide()`, `add()`, etc. type of arithmetic operations which perform near real time... I bet after using inbuilt methods you may get 10x times boost in speed.

Comment: Or if you can precisely define what steps you want to perform in details then I can accurately tell you the methods required for the desired processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (I haven't opened the text editor, but it seems) that you need to generate the entire image in HSV and then call cvtColor once for the entire image. Meaning that you should call cvtColor once instead of once for every pixel. That should give you a significant boost in speed.

You would do this:

```
  cvtColor(dst, dst, CV_BGR2HSV);

  for (int y = 0; y < dst.rows; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < dst.cols; x++) {


        Vec3b pixel = dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x); // read current pixel 
         double H = pixel.val[0];
         double S = pixel.val[1];
         double V = pixel.val[2];
           h = H;
           l = (2 - S) * V;
           s = s * V;
           s /= (l <= 1) ? (l) : 2 - (l);
           l /= 2;

           H = h;
           l *= 2;
           s *= (l <= 1) ? l : 2 - l;
           V = (l + s) / 2;
           S = (2 * s) / (l + s);

           pixel.val[0] = H;
           pixel.val[1] = S;
           pixel.val[2] = V;
    }
}

cvtColor(dst, dst, CV_HSV2BGR);
```

Comment: I see i get what you mean, but i have to set the L for every pixel, i havent found how to set the lightness for the whole image, that's why i'm setting to each pixel.